# Adding custom values to ComboBox with CompositeCollection

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, combobox, compositecollection

I'm new to WPF. I have a combobox which when choosing a value three other fields (`AbbrBlock`, `MultiBrandSupplier`, `IgnoreNoCompetition`) update along to show the correct relevant values according to the data source. No problem with this.

Issue arises when I try to add to the combobox a custom value, although the combobox shows all values correctly, the other fields don't change when changing the combobox's value.

Here's the working code (without the additional custom combobox value - stripped to the key pieces):

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:OrdersDataSet x:Key="ordersDataSet" />
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="caSuppliersViewSource" Source="{Binding CaSuppliers, Source={StaticResource ordersDataSet}}"/>
</Window.Resources>

...

<StackPanel DataContext="{StaticResource caSuppliersViewSource}">
    <ComboBox Name="SupplierDropdown" DisplayMemberPath="SupplierName" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=caSuppliersViewSource}}"/>
    <TextBlock Name="AbbrBlock" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Abbr}"/>
    <CheckBox Name="MultiBrandSupplier" IsChecked="{Binding MultiBrand}"/>
    <CheckBox Name="IgnoreNoCompetition" IsChecked="{Binding IgnoreNoCompetition}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Here's the code with the added custom value which shows correctly but the other fields don't update when changing the combobox value:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:OrdersDataSet x:Key="ordersDataSet" />
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="caSuppliersViewSource" Source="{Binding CaSuppliers, Source={StaticResource ordersDataSet}}"/>
</Window.Resources>

...

<StackPanel DataContext="{StaticResource caSuppliersViewSource}">
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <CompositeCollection x:Key="myCompositeCollection">
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=caSuppliersViewSource}}" />
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Add New..." />
        </CompositeCollection>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <ComboBox Name="SupplierDropdown" DisplayMemberPath="SupplierName" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myCompositeCollection}}"/>
    <TextBlock Name="AbbrBlock" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Abbr}"/>
    <CheckBox Name="MultiBrandSupplier" IsChecked="{Binding MultiBrand}"/>
    <CheckBox Name="IgnoreNoCompetition" IsChecked="{Binding IgnoreNoCompetition}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Does `caSuppliersViewSource` have a property named `Abbr`? I'm struggling to understand that part.

Comment: @EdPlunkett `caSuppliersViewSource` was created automatically by Visual Studio when dragging `ordersDataSet` from the DataSource panel, which in turn is linked to a database in SQL Server. In short, `caSuppliersViewSource` derives from a table which has a column named `abbr`.

Comment: Ok. Can you describe exactly what you see in the UI now (screenshot would be great) and exactly what you *want* to see (same screenshot crudely edited in MS paint would be perfect)?

Comment: Are you saying that when you select an existing combo box item, you expect its properties to display in `AbbrBlock` etc., but they don't?

Comment: Exactly. The first code above works great but the combobox doesn't show the additional item, and when adding the custom item as shown in the later code block, `AbbrBlock` and the other two checkboxes don't update to display the correct information.

Comment: But `AddrBlock` etc. display something valid at some other time? Are you saying that those controls update when you *change the XAML and run the application again*, or when you change something in the UI at runtime? What does "Adding the custom item" mean? Does that mean adding an item to the collection at runtime, or does it refer to adding the "Add New..." item in the XAML? If I wanted to pull teeth, I'd be a dentist.

Comment: What is "the correct information"? Where does it come from? How are you providing it? When do you expect it to appear? What are you seeing instead?

Comment: Basically what I mean is that when using the first code above (just the values of the db table) it works as expected, meaning `AbbrBlock` shows the correct value according to the value selected in the combobox (the value of a different column in the same row of the db table), but when using the second code (which adds the "Add New...") the `AbbrBlock` doesn't change when selecting a different value in the combobox, it just shows the value of the first row in the db table.

Comment: Ah, OK. I think what's happening is that when you bind `caSuppliersViewSource` to `ComboBox.ItemsSource`, the combobox updates `caSuppliersViewSource.SelectedItem` correctly (it sees its got a CollectionViewSource). But when you bury `caSuppliersViewSource` in a `CompositeCollection` and bind that, `caSuppliersViewSource.SelectedItem` gets ignored because the ComboBox doesn't even know it's in there. So... You *could* try binding that directly on the ComboBox, and see how that works: `SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Source={StaticResource caSuppliersViewSource}"`. Might work or might not.

Comment: Might throw an exception when you select the "Add New..." item, dunno.

Comment: So should I leave everything as is and just add the `SelectedItem` line to the combobox? (Is the second `SelectedItem` on that line intentional? VS doesn't allow it.)

Comment: Sorry, wrong property of CollectionViewSource -- try `SelectedItem="{Binding View.CurrentItem, Source={StaticResource caSuppliersViewSource}}"`

Comment: Where do I put that code?

Comment: That's your SelectedItem attribute on the ComboBox. It's not working for me, but the underlying collection is different for you so give it a shot. The idea is to try to update the CurrentItem property of the collectionviewsource explicitly, since that's not happening automagically any more.

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't work by me neither. I don't see any change after adding it to the combobox. This is what the combobox has now: `<ComboBox Name="SupplierDropdown" DisplayMemberPath="SupplierName" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myCompositeCollection}}" SelectedItem="{Binding View.CurrentItem, Source={StaticResource caSuppliersViewSource}}" />`

Comment: Sorry, that was an overcomplicated way to do it anyway, even if it had actually worked -- see my answer. Pretty sure that'll work.

Comment: You're answer works! Thank you so so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the `ComboBox` was updating `caSuppliersViewSource`'s `View.CurrentItem` property (I think) to match its `SelectedItem` in your first snippet. In the second, the `CollectionViewSource` is buried inside a `CompositeCollection` so that doesn't happen any more. However, the `ComboBox` is still selecting an item, and you can just bind to that using `ElementName`. No need for setting the `DataContext` on the `StackPanel` with this version.

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <CompositeCollection x:Key="myCompositeCollection">
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=caSuppliersViewSource}}" />
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Add New..." />
        </CompositeCollection>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <ComboBox 
        Name="SupplierDropdown" 
        DisplayMemberPath="SupplierName" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myCompositeCollection}}"
        />
    <TextBlock 
        Name="AbbrBlock" 
        VerticalAlignment="Center" 
        Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Abbr, ElementName=SupplierDropdown}"
        />
    <CheckBox 
        Name="MultiBrandSupplier" 
        IsChecked="{Binding SelectedItem.MultiBrand, ElementName=SupplierDropdown}"
        />
    <CheckBox 
        Name="IgnoreNoCompetition" 
        IsChecked="{Binding SelectedItem.IgnoreNoCompetition, ElementName=SupplierDropdown}"
        />
</StackPanel>
```

You could also give eyour viewmodel a `SelectedDBItem` property of the same type as whatever `caSuppliersViewSource` contains, and bind `ComboBox.SelectedItem` to that. Then you could do this:

```
    <TextBlock 
        Name="AbbrBlock" 
        VerticalAlignment="Center" 
        Text="{Binding SelectedDBItem}"
        />
```

But that's six dozen of one, half of another, or something -- unless you want to do something else with `SelectedDBItem` in your viewmodel, then it's handy.